# Background Sprites not showing in ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Im cross browser testing and i have come across an issue in ie8 that doesnt show my background social sprites which work in all other browsers.

here is my code:

```
    <!-- Social Icon List -->
<ul class="social-icons">
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a title="Follow us on Twitter" href="#"><span class="social"> </span></a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a title="Follow us on facebook" href="#"><span class="social fbook"> </span></a></li>
    <li style="text-align: center;"><a title="Follow us on Youtube play" href="#"><span class="social gplay"> </span></a></li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: center;">#DecadeInTheCity</p>
<!-- Ends Social Icon List -->
```

and the css:

```
.social{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    margin-top:7px;
    background:url(../../uploads/2014/11/social-icons.png)no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    background-position:left top;
    text-indent:-5000px;
}

.entry-content-wrapper div li {
    text-indent: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
}

.fbook{
    background-position:-32px;
}

.instagram{
    background-position:-64px;
}

.gplay{
    background-position:-96px;
}
```

is there anything i can do to make it display?

thanks, Ricky.

Comment: IE-8 isn't very good at handling PNG files especially as background images. Try another format.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but all i had to do was put a space between )no-repeat to ) no-repeat and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use inline style then it will work for you.

Like below -

```
<li style="text-align: center;"><a title="Follow us on Twitter" href="#"><span class="social" style="background:url('../../uploads/2014/11/social-icons.png') no-repeat;"> </span></a></li>
```